# JMS listener - dynamically choose destinations

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

I have many destinations (queues) on ActiveMQ deployed on a separate server. I want to dynamically listen to these destinations from my program. Currently I'm listening to these destinations as shown below:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover://(tcp://192.168.25.26:61616)" />        
</bean>

<bean id="myMessageListener" class="MyMessageListener"></bean>

<jms:listener-container
    container-type="default"
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
    acknowledge="auto" >
        <jms:listener destination="TEST.FOO" ref="myMessageListener" />
        <jms:listener destination="foo.bas" ref="myMessageListener" />
        <jms:listener destination="foo.bar" ref="myMessageListener" />        
</jms:listener-container>
```

I'm able to successfully receive messages from these destinations. However, as you can see I've to add destinations manually in the above configuration. I want to skip this and prefer  the listener to dynamically choose the destinations. Is this possible? How? Many thanks in advance for any sort of help/guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation on [Composite Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/composite-destinations.html) and [Destination Wildcards](http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html), these two features would allow you to have something close to what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to dynamically create a listener for a particular destination? In my above code, I'm explicitly binding a listener with a destination. I want the listener to bind to a destination dynamically based on the message it receives/listens. Help is appreciated.

Comment: I've seen code using this: `org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver` for such task. I'm new to Spring/JMS so I'm unable to understand it wholly.