# activemq round robin between queues or topics

Tags: activemq-classic, load-balancing, round-robin

I'm trying to achieve load balancing between different types of messages. I would not know in advance what the messages coming in might be until they hit the queue. I know I can try resequencing the messages, but I was thinking that maybe if there was a way to have the various consumers round robin between either queues or between topics, this would solve my problem.

The main problem i'm trying to solve is that I have many services sending messages to one queue with many consumers feeding off one queue. I do not want one type of service monopolizing the entire worker cluster. Again I don't know in advance what the messages that are going to hit the queue are going to be.

To try to clearly repeat my question:
Is there a way to tell the consumers to round robin between either existing queues or topics?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question on another post just had to know to look there. I resolved my problem by not creating AMQ consumer but a JMS listener with a composite destination as specified in this post: [jms-listener-dynamically-choose-destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257230/jms-listener-dynamically-choose-destinations). It turns out the JMS listener automatically round robins though all the queues you assign to it.

Answer (score 1):

Consumers on a Queue will already do round robin processing of the messages on the Queue.  The one thing to keep in mind is consumer [prefetch](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) which can allow one consumer to grab many messages before others arrive on the Queue so you may need to adjust prefetch depending on your scenario.

Read up on the differences between Queue and Topic [here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I know that the consumers themselves will automatically be round robin, but will a single consumer round robin between multiple queues and/or topics that it's subscribing to?

Comment: Consumers can only subscribe to one destination.

Comment: OH.. what about topics? can a consumer subscribe to multiple topics?

Comment: Nope, you need one consumer instance per queue or topic.

Comment: see my answer below, you actually gave me a solution a few years ago on another post. I just didn't realize I should be looking at JMS listeners.